# Is there overhead when calling await on already split context?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, overhead

EDIT: My question doesn't really make sense because I was misunderstanding how tasks work. I've marked stephen cleary's answer as accepted because it pointed me in the direction to learn my mistakes.

I often see code like this:

```
public async Task DoSomething(){
     await DoSomethingElse();
     await DoSoManyThings();
     await DoEverything();
}
```

Now the way I see this is that the first await starts a second thread and returns control to the calling thread. When the await finishes, the second await is called. Now this is where i might be confused. The second await splits context / creates new thread and the other thread disappears(returns to caller). Is there an overhead to this? If so, how much? IS it better to have my code as follows, to avoid creating new thread for no reason:

```
public async Task DoSomething(){
     await DoSomethingElse();
      DoSoManyThings();
      DoEverything();
}
```

Here is a full code example showing what I mean, as requested. 
The loop is there to ensure the awaited code isn't instantly completed. Output is identical for both test functions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program test = new Program();
            Task firstTest = test.StartMultipleAwaitTest();
            firstTest.Wait();
            test.StartSingleAwaitTest();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public async Task StartSingleAwaitTest() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nStarting second test");
            await FirstTask();
            SecondTask();
            ThirdTask();
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }

        public async Task StartMultipleAwaitTest() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            await FirstTask();
            await SecondTask();
            await ThirdTask();
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }

        public async Task FirstTask() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start First task");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { }
            Console.WriteLine("End Firt task");
        }

        public async Task SecondTask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Second task");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { }
            Console.WriteLine("End Second task");
        }

        public async Task ThirdTask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Third task");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { }
            Console.WriteLine("End Third task");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second method may not work if DoEveryThing requires output from DoSoManyThings().  Yes there is overhead but minimal.  Every Program and Process has some overhead and the thread is approximately the same overhead.

Comment: From my understanding both of my code example should work in the exact same way. That is, the 2nd func is never called until the 1st completes and the 3rd is never called until the 2nd completes. Are you just guessing that the overhead is the same, do you have any reason/source?

Comment: _"the first await starts a second thread and returns control to the calling thread"_ -- just because something is `async`, that doesn't mean it creates a new thread. Assuming no changes to the methods being called and they really are asynchronous, the two examples do _not_ work the same way; in the 2nd, the `DoEverything()` method will be called before the async operation started by `DoSoManyThings()` has completed, while in the 1st it won't be called until after.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by "split context"; assuming a non-default synchronization context, each `await` will return to the original context when the operation completes. In any case, your question is too broad as asked. Please narrow your scenario to the point where you can provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you are asking.

Comment: Full example added. I say split context because new thread is run on a new context, although perhaps not the clearest way to ask my question.

Comment: The overhead is minimal *compared* to the delays induced by any kind of asynchronous I/O, basically. You don't use `await` for computing `40 + 2` - you use it for awaiting a DB operation, for example. Either it completes synchronously (which negates the overhead entirely), or it doesn't (which means it's going to take a long, long time in CPU time scales). And again, as Peter already said, you're not starting any new threads here - your example is 100% synchronous, and is never going to change threads. `await` *doesn't* start any new threads - it just asynchronously awaits an awaitable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had some major flaws in my understanding of tasks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first await starts a second thread and returns control to the calling thread.

No. `await` most emphatically does **not** start a second thread. I have a blog post describing [what `await` *does* do in detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

> Output is identical for both test functions.

The reason the output is identical is because in both cases, all functions run synchronously. Pay attention to your compiler warnings; in this case, the compiler will give you warnings on your `FirstTask` method (and friends), stating that these methods will run synchronously.

What's actually happening in the `StartMultipleAwaitTest` test is that the methods have run to completion before the `await` even examines the `Task`. Similarly, in the `StartSingleAwaitTest` test, the methods also synchronously run to completion before returning to `StartSingleAwaitTest`.

A more real-world test (i.e., doing asynchronous work in an asynchronous method) will give you more real-world results:

```
public async Task FirstTask() 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Start First task");
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
  Console.WriteLine("End Firt task");
}

public async Task SecondTask()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Start Second task");
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
  Console.WriteLine("End Second task");
}

public async Task ThirdTask()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Start Third task");
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
  Console.WriteLine("End Third task");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had some major flaws in my understanding of tasks, your blog post and some other sources helped clear it up for me. I've marked your answer as correct even though it doesn't really answer my question, though this is because my question doesn't really make sense!